# Is it possible to reset $@ and $# to parse the list of positional arguments more than once?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a common script (`common.sh`) that parses some arguments. 
Other scripts import it using `source common.sh`. 
Is there a way to reset `$@` and `$#`,
so I can use the below code for argument parsing multiple times?

I start by saving the original script arguments,
so they are available after argument parsing has run:

```
readonly script_args=("${@}")
```

But, this only saves the arguments;
it doesn't make it possible to run argument parsing using `shift`
more than once.

**Argument parsing**:

```
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]]; do
    case "$1" in
    --command=*)
        command="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --project=*)
        project="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --workspace=*)
        workspace="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --account=*)
        account="${1#*=}"
        ;;
    --debug)
        debug="true"
        ;;
    "")
        log_debug "Empty argument"
        ;;
    *)
        log_error "Invalid argument: ${1}"
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
    shift
done
```

Answer (score 15):

In Bourne-like shells, in addition to settings shell options, `set` can be used to set the positional parameters.

```
set -- "${script_args[@]}"
```

`--` is needed:

1. to mark the end of options so that if the first element of `$script_args` starts with `-` or `+`, it's not taken as option.
2. to work around the fact that when no arguments are passed to `set`, it prints the list of variables (and functions in some shells) instead of making the positional parameters an empty list.

`"${script_args[@]}"`, which *must* be quoted is Korn shell syntax that extends the `"$@"` expansion of the Bourne shell to expand to all the elements in the array. That syntax is also supported by `zsh`, `bash` and `yash`.

In all those¹ but `yash`, you could also use

```
set - "${script_args[@]}"
```

In zsh, you could also use:

```
argv=( "$script_args[@]" )
```

In `yash`, you could also use:

```
set -- "$script_args"
```

The equivalent in `rc` or derivatives would be:

```
* = $script_args
```

In `fish`:

```
set argv $script_args
```

In `csh`/`tcsh` (the first shell to support arrays in the late 70s)

```
set argv = ($script_args:q)
```

---

<sup>¹ The Bourne shell didn't support `--` there until SysIII in 1981 but always supported `-`. It was not really an option delimiter, it was just that only the first argument was considered for options (like for `sh`) and that `-` is an empty list of options.</sup>

Comment: They may also want to set OPTIND to 1 if they need to use getopts more than once. But seeing that they use some homegrown parsing, that would not be necessary.